# Gate Driver Circuit Question

Tags: power-electronics, texas-instruments, gate-driving

I read the [PoE PD Schematic Review Guidelines](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaf59/slvaf59.pdf?ts=1626186506397&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), and there is a gate driver circuit I don't understand how that works. Can someone tell me how to work?

1.) On the page 22, the dotted boxes are the gate drives, I never use that kind of driver before, so I have no idea how to work.

2.) What's the function of R31 and C31?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An active-clamped forward (ACF) lend itself well to self-driven synchronous rectification in the secondary side. By self-driven, I mean you can use the transformer output voltage to directly drive the MOSFETs gates. Contrary to what a classical 3-winding forward brings, the drive voltage with an ACF is available as long as the primary side is magnetized and thus provides adequate bias to the output MOSFETs. However, as you know, the raw output voltage of the forward - the voltage at the secondary winding - depends on the input voltage and transformer turns ratio. Therefore, depending on the input-output parameters, it may appears that the voltage delivered by the transformer exceeds the maximum gate-source voltage of the selected MOSFET. It is usually 20 V but depending on the selected type, it may vary.

If you apply too high a \$V_{GS}\$ voltage to a MOSFET or drive it too close to its maximum rating, you reduce its operating life time and if spikes superimpose on the driving voltage already high, there is no margin and you may destroy the part. For this reason, you need a clamp on the drive voltage if the turns ratio or the input voltage are too high. The proposed clamped in the TI AN is shown below:

[image]

The transistor is wired in a simple linear regulator whose output voltage is simply that of the Zener (biased by \$R_{29}\$) minus the \$V_{be}\$ drop. Nothing fancy here and the secret lies in selecting the right transistor capable of delivering enough current to ensure clean transitions. \$D_{14}\$ is there to protect \$Q_5\$ against reverse bias. So when the node 9 of the transformer goes high, \$Q_5\$ drives the MOSFET with a voltage of roughly 12-0.65 = 11.3 V.

It works in a similar way when the transformer polarity reverses and activates the controlled free-wheel transistor \$Q_6\$ which receives the same drive voltage as with \$Q_5\$. However, because this a heavy CCM operation, you cannot afford to have shoot-through currents and \$Q_6\$ must be quickly turned off via \$Q_7\$. To quickly evacuate the minority carriers when the bipolar conducts, you can install a network such as \$R_{31}C_{31}\$, this is a classic in bipolar drive. What you want is a bit of negative voltage at turn off on the bipolar base which will accelerate the evacuation of the minority carriers, effectively turning off the bipolar transistor. What is important is the time constant matching: \$R_{31}C_{31}\approx t_s\$ in which \$t_s\$ represents the storage time of the transistor - if I remember well my course on bipolar transistors which is probably under a heap of dust now :-)

Comment: Hi Kint 
Your answer is very clear to me. 
and I have two-part I cannot get it, hope you can give me some advice.
1. I need to put R29 resistor to drive the Zener, I mean if the voltage across the Zener above 12V the Zener starts work, why need to add the R29 resistor.
2.Where I can see your course.

Comment: You need \$R_{29}\$ not only to bias the Zener diode but also to drive \$Q_5\$. The Zener is there to stop the base excursion beyond 12 V when the forward primary-side transistor turns on.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. 

Do you know where I can find the gate driver design example, after your explanation, I know how it works but I want to know how to design C31 and R31 value, or can you suggest to me some useful books to let me can refer to.

Comment: This is old stuff and no longer documented I'm afraid. I have found this [document](http://didier.magnon.free.fr/cours/commutation%20chapitreIII.pdf) in French which recommends to match the time constant of the bases resistance and the capacitor with the bipolar storage time. I believe this also can be done by adding a cap. with different values over the base resistance and finding the sweet spot on the switching characteristics. This is a cheap solution anyway as \$t_s\$ heavily changes with temperature.

Comment: Why adding C31 and R31 can quickly turn off the Q6, is it OK I do not need to add R31 and C31?

Comment: Run a quick simulation to see the effects of a RC driving another R (the base resistance) and C (the \$C_{be}\$ capacitance). You create a pole-zero pair and depending which one dominates, you either integrate or differentiate. In the second case, a negative voltage at the base is generated and you extract the carriers faster than with a 0-V bias.